# Jquery extends element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to extend the functionality of my textarea element. The textarea elements should respond when I call a method like this:

```
$('#jsedit').jsedit();
```

I know it can be done by doing like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.fn.extend({
        jsedit: function() {
            alert(this.val());
        }
    });
});
```

but how can I specify only the textarea can do this?
Because now every element can called jsedit() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.fn.extend({
        jsedit: function() {
            if ($(this).is('textarea')) {
                 //your stuff
            }
        }
    });
});

console.log($('#your_textarea').jsedit());
```

**EDIT**: complete statement

lg,

flo

Comment: or, pure javascript too: `if(this.nodeName === 'TEXTAREA') { ... }`